# How to add jquery button style to make background icon transparent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

I have the solution and it works fine if I put it in the markup:

```
//class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" title="Close all" style="cursor:pointer;background-image: url(content/jquery/jquery-ui/1.8.21/css/ui-lightness/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png);"
```

However I need to add all that info in the code below and I cant find the right sintax:

```
$(objID).button
    ({
        icons:
        {
          primary: "ui-icon-closethick { margin:10px; }",
        },
        text: false
    }).click(function() {
            alert("Clicked!");
    });
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: geez i dont even know what that means... just using a forum to get some help...thanks anyways

Comment: You can accept answer in your older questions, if they helped you. This way the people helping you get a little reputation and some people are more likely to help you for it. Make sure to read how this *forum* works in the http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

Just put the styles in a class and use `.addClass()` in the click event..

```
.button
{
   cursor:pointer;
   background-image: url(content/jquery/jquery-ui/1.8.21/css/ui-lightness/
                         images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png);
}

.click(function() {
            alert("Clicked!");
           $(this).addClass('button');
    });
```

Comment: that did not work :(
Also, I need the image bound to the button when I call that portion of the code, not when I click on the button. thanks for replying.

Comment: Getting closer, pointer works but image wont display:

...
var header =  "<td style=\"font-size:2.2em;\" width=\"3%\"><span id=\"CloseAllWindows" + "\"</span></td>"

...

span.CloseAllWindowsButton
{
   cursor:pointer;
   background-image: url(content/jquery/jquery-ui/1.8.21/css/ui-lightness/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png);
}

//TO DO: check why the background image is not being applied / cursor is being applied

$(objID).addClass('CloseAllWindowsButton');